# How can you render a div after an image click?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a box when the image is clicked. I have this code in where the box is rendered depending on where the user clicks. As we take the coordinates. But whenever I click the image, nothing happens. When I put this onClick function inside the img tag and I click the image, the whole page goes completely blank. I want the box to be rendered on different parts of the image depending on where the user clicks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import mainImage from '../img/marioBrosMain.jpg'
import '../main.css'
import Box from '../pages/box.js'

function Main() {

  const [style, setStyle] = useState();

  const imageClick = (x, y) => {
    return `position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 2px solid red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: 1450px;
            left:${x}px;
            top:${y}px;`
  }

    return (
        <div id="frame">
          <div id="mainImage" style = {style} onClick={e => {
            const newStyle =
          imageClick(e.target.screenX,
                         e.target.screenY);

          setStyle(newStyle);
        }}></div>
          <img src={mainImage} className="marioBros____image" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is may help you, I have only changed in onClick event and imageClick() function

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import mainImage from '../img/marioBrosMain.jpg'
import '../main.css'
import Box from '../pages/box.js'

function Main() {

  const [style, setStyle] = useState();

  const imageClick = (x, y) => {

    let newStyle = `position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 2px solid red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: 1450px;
            left:${x}px;
            top:${y}px;`

    setStyle(newStyle);

  }

    return (
        <div id="frame">
          <div id="mainImage" style = {style} onClick={e => {
          imageClick(e.target.screenX, e.target.screenY);
        }}></div>
          <img src={mainImage} className="marioBros____image" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

`screenX` and `screenY` are properties of [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenX) and not `EventTarget`.

Change
`imageClick(e.target.screenX, e.target.screenY);`

to

`imageClick(e.screenX,e.screenY);`

and try again.

You can verify that `e.target.screenX`/`e.target.screenY` must be coming as `undefined` when you log them too

Also since it's a react code, you need to return/set valid `style` object (`newStyle` must be an object) with [camelCase](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) for your CSS properties.